# Data inserted in database, but ajax calls error function

Tags: php, ajax, forms, errors

I'm new to wordpress and I am having a problem with ajax while submitting form. Form is submited fine, data is inserted in table, but ajax is calling an error function.
This is my form

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="order-form" novalidate>
                <label for="name"><?php echo __('Ime i prezime', 'mojaobuca'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo __('Unesite Vaše ime i prezime', 'mojaobuca'); ?>">
                <label for="email"><?php echo __('Vaša email adresa', 'mojaobuca'); ?></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo __('Unesite Vašu email adresu', 'mojaobuca'); ?>">
                <label for="address"><?php echo __('Vaša adresa', 'mojaobuca'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo __('Unesite Vašu adresu', 'mojaobuca'); ?>">
                <label for="city"><?php echo __('Vaš grad', 'mojaobuca'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo __('Unesite Vaš grad', 'mojaobuca'); ?>">
                <label for="phone"><?php echo __('Vaš telefon', 'mojaobuca'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo __('Unesite Vaš telefon', 'mojaobuca'); ?>">
                <label for="shoe-num"><?php echo __('Broj obuće', 'mojaobuca'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="shoe_num" id="shoe_num" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo __('Unesite broj obuće', 'mojaobuca'); ?>">
                <label for="color"><?php echo __('Boja obuće', 'mojaobuca'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="color" id="color" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo __('Unesite boju obuće', 'mojaobuca'); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="<?php echo get_field('obuca_code'); ?>">
                <?php if(!get_field('obuca_discount')): ?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="shoe_price" name="shoe_price" value="<?php echo get_field('obuca_price'); ?>">
                <?php else: ?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="shoe_price" name="shoe_price" value="<?php echo get_field('obuca_discount'); ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="#"></div>
                <a href="#"
                   name="order-shoe"
                   class="secondary push-down"
                   id="order"
                   ><?php echo __('Poruči', 'mojaobuca') ?></a>
            </form>
```

This is where I registered ajax in functions.php

```
wp_register_script( 'ajaxscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'ajaxscript', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
```

This is my function for inserting data

```
function mojaobuca_save_order() {
global $wpdb;
$result = '';

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$name = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = sanitize_email($_REQUEST['email']);
$address = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['address']);
$city = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['city']);
$phone = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['phone']);
$shoe_num = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['shoe-num']);
$color = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['color']);
$product_id = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['product_id']);
$price = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['shoe_price']);
$date = date('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'orders';

$captcha = $_POST["response"];

$secretKey = '6LdZ0jMUAAAAAO_rRNXsHrlH2O9oPh4rHkqwkKLE';
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secretKey . "&response=" . $captcha;
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

if(!$captcha){
    var_dump('captcha ne valja');
    echo 'grecap error';
}
if($response['success'] == false) {
    var_dump('error');
    echo 'error';
} else {
    var_dump('priprema a upis');
    $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'address' => $address,
        'city' => $city,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'number' => $shoe_num,
        'color' => $color,
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'price' => $price,
        'date' => $date
    );

    $format = array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');

    $wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);
    $result = 'success';
}
echo $result;
wp_die();
```

}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mojaobuca_save_order', 'mojaobuca_save_order');
add_action('wp_ajax_mojaobuca_save_order', 'mojaobuca_save_order');

And this is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#order').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#order-form').validate();
    var name = $('input#name').val();
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    var address = $('input#address').val();
    var city = $('input#city').val();
    var phone = $('input#phone').val();
    var shoeNum = $('input#shoe-num').val();
    var color = $('input#color').val();
    var shoe_price = $('input#shoe_price').val();
    var product_id = $('input#product_id').val();
    var grecap = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
        async: false,
        data: {
            name : name,
            email : email,
            address : address,
            city : city,
            phone : phone,
            shoeNum : shoeNum,
            color : color,
            response : response,
            shoe_price: shoe_price,
            product_id: product_id,
            action: "mojaobuca_save_order"
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            $('div.success-msg').show();
            $('#order-form').hide();
            $('#order-form').resetForm();

        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert('error');
            $('div.error-msg').show();
            $('#order-form').hide();
            $('#order-form').resetForm();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. Works fine without dataType: `json` in `ajax-script.js` and `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in php file

Comment: This is not answered! Please send a comment.